# Interacting with a webview (JAVA ANDROID)

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, webview

In my app I have a webview to show the user some information from a web page. Before seeing the info though, you have to choose an option on a dropdown list on the webpage. Is there any way I can choose the right option for the user (via code) and only have them see the content?

Answer (score 0):

You can run arbitrary javascript inside a `WebView`, initiated from Java. Be sure you have javascript enabled. Once you've done that,

```
theWebView.loadUrl( "javascript:alert('Hello')" );
```

is the mechanism to invoke javascript functions or scripts. To pre-select a drop-down, you may want to include jquery or such, making the selection easier.